# My php echo statements do not output expected array contents from SQL query

Tags: php, sql, arrays, echo

I have the following code which selects ID's of a database with many regions in it.  I create the array as follows:

```
$old2 = $this->query("SELECT regionid FROM theregions WHERE regionparent = '808'");
$old2_array = mysqli_fetch_array($old2);
```

And then I try and output the array like so:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($old2)) {
    echo $row[0] . '<br>';
}
```

It produces the following:

```
800
834
933
```

However, if I use phpMyAdmin and run the same SQL statement, I get:

```
604
800
834
933
```

If I try using print_r(array_values($old2_array)); I get:

```
Array ( [0] => 604 [1] => 604 )
```

Have searched many SO pages, and have tried this:

```
$length = count($old2_array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  echo $old2_array[$i], "<br />";
};
```

...which produces:

```
604

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /index.php on line 128
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is not to have that second line.  Once I remove this:

```
$old2_array = mysqli_fetch_array($old2);
```

Then the following loop works:

```
while( $reg = $old2->fetch_object() ) {
    echo $reg->region_id . "<br>";
}
```

For some reason, the mysqli_fetch_array() statement screws with following commands.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that php echo do not handles arrays directly but you have to use a syntax that includes curvy brackets if Im right.
if I were you, I would use php `var_dump(array_here)`
or load the array variable into a single variable first before echo it

Comment: Thank you.  It turns out that this is the solution:

  while( $reg = $old2->fetch_object() ) {
    echo $reg->region_id . "<br>";
  }